# Parallel or multiple requests through Bash cURL

Tags: bash, curl

I have this simple program where I am sending URLS and requesting server to process that Url and send back results to be saved in the file;  all through the loop one by one. It runs fine but only problem is I have 5,000 links or URLS to be processed and it takes a long time with one by one loop. Input Urls are different from each other and do not have pattern. Is there anyway I can pass on 10,20 or 30 requests in parallel and save their results in one file as well?
here is my code. Thanks

```
USER_GUID=$1
API_KEY=$2
EXTRACTOR_GUID=$3
URL_FILE=$4
DATA_FILE=$5

while read URL
do
    echo -n $URL
    curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s -d "{\"input\":{\"webpage/url\":\"$URL\"}}" "https://api.io/store/connector/$EXTRACTOR_GUID/_query?_user=$USER_GUID&_apikey=$API_KEY" >> $DATA_FILE
    echo "" >> $DATA_FILE
    echo " ...done"
done < $URL_FILE
```

Comment: While is possible to create a paralell running script, the easiet way for you will be simply split the `URL_FILE` to 30 parts and run the script 30 times, each with different `url_file1 ... url_file30`. you will get 30 output files what can join together with a simple `cat`.

Comment: Could that be done through one script?

Comment: Sure. But the work and complications doesn't worth. You will still end with 30 parallel curl, so whats the point?

Answer (score 3):

Use GNU Parallel

```
cat $URL_FILE | parallel -j30 -q curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s -d "{\"input\":{\"webpage/url\":\"$URL\"}}" "https://api.io/store/connector/$EXTRACTOR_GUID/_query?_user=$USER_GUID&_apikey=$API_KEY" >> $DATA_FILE
```